# jsTree opened node attributes... how to get?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jstree

I am new to jsTree and have some problems getting some attributes of the nodes. Here is my code...

```
var $myTree = $('#treeDiv').html(res).jstree({
        ...options
    }).on("loaded.jstree", function () {
        $myTree.jstree('open_node', '#' + IdToOpen, false, true);
    });

    $myTree.bind("open_node.jstree", this.onNodeOpen);

function onNodeOpen(event, data){...here i want to get some of the attributes of opened node};
```

my nodes have this structure

```
<li><a href='#' id='some guid' rel='some string' accesskey='some number'>Title of node</a></li>
```

now i want to retrieve id, rel and accesskey attribute values in onNodeOpen function, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.rslt.obj` contains an jquery extended version of the node that was clicked:

so to retrieve the id:

```
var id = data.rslt.obj.attr("id")
```

I prepared a small jsfiddle which shows you this in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/ak4Ed/144/

Comment: I have tried to get it using the same code but i got an error that attr('id') is undefined... may be the thing is that the node is not clicked when it is just opened... because when i handle dblclick.jstree event your code works fine but not for open_node event????

Comment: Did you try the jsfiddle i just added?

Comment: I think my problem was that i assigned id to the <a> not to the <li>... thanks

Comment: In that case you should be able to just do ```data.rslt.obj.children("a").attr("id")```.